# Why don't my points display in Haskell OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell, graphics, 3d

I am trying to generate a terrain using [Haskell and OpenGL](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1). When I run the code, it works (it displays a black window), but no points appear. Where am I going wrong?

```
import Data.Int
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

type Terrain = [(GLint, GLint, GLint)]

points = generateFlatTerrain 100 100 0

generateFlatTerrain :: Int32 -> Int32 -> Int32 -> Terrain
generateFlatTerrain width height depth = 
    [(x, y, z) | x <- [1..width], y <- [1..height], z <- [depth]]

drawTerrain :: Terrain -> IO ()
drawTerrain terrain = renderPrimitive Points
                      $ mapM_ (\(x, y, z) -> vertex $ Vertex3 x y z) terrain

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello, world!"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  drawTerrain points
  flush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the simplest answer ever is: OpenGL's coordinate space is [-1..1]. Therefore I modified my code:

```
[-1, -1 + 1 / width,..1], ......
```

Comment: ["Your scale is wildly wrong: the scene is vastly larger than you expect. You are viewing a single texel on a single triangle in the scene."](http://dmalcolm.livejournal.com/2433.html) Just 39 more failure modes to go until you're an OpenGL expert!